# How to customise wordpress user authentication

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

I have a old website, which allow people to register and do staff. Say it is www.example.com.

Now I added a subdomain, reviews.example.com and want my users to write reviews.
The reviews.example.com is done in wordpress which works perfectly.

However, as my users already registered with the old site, ideally I want my user to use their old username and password to login to the review website. Also I would like new users to continue register in the old site and I could just write another query to insert the new user's username and password into wordpress's user table.

To custom login process for wordpress, can I apply a callback somewhere, so when wordpress login failed, I will run my custom query and create and return a wp_User object?

Or it is better to change the login code in wordpress directly? I searched wordpress code and saw the code where I could hack to put my own login logic.

Comment: you can simply install wordpress and import your sql database after that truncate your wp-User table and import the wp-user(previous which are having users data) and the same wordpress users will be able to signup and the previous users can sign-in

Comment: my main site is certainly not on wordpress, also I perfer people to keep main site as it is and modify the new wordpress blog.

Comment: how many users register any approx idea?

Comment: I have 200 users at the moment, also why that make difference? For me, modify or callback wordpress is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Then one solution can be done 
i.e

> I am assuming that you made the username field and the password field
>   of registering and the password is visible for you.

Now once you make the wordpress install at your blog.website.com and then you need to copy the sql query which have import for your previous_users and paste in your SQL query of phpmyadmin after that you just need to add the same feild in your database as the wp-users feilds are containing then after that make your users password as MD5 crypt for that you just need to change the password type feild to MD5 crypt and your all users will be able to sign-in there.

I hope i Am clear to you.
Any Doubt you can Comment.